# IconMenu doesn't appear in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [material-ui](http://material-ui.com/). I tried to implement [Icon Menu](http://material-ui.com/#/components/icon-menus). My component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {IconMenu} from 'material-ui';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <IconMenu
        iconButtonElement={<div>Tried IconButton instead if this div here</div>}
        >
        <MenuItem primaryText='Logout' />
      </IconMenu>
    )
  }
});
```

When I click on icon button element (div with text in this case) nothing happens. What an I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad. I forgot to include React-Tap-Event-Plugin that is [required](http://material-ui.com/#/get-started).